# Why is の needed in 行くのでしょうか but it is not needed in 行きますでしょうか?

Tags: grammar

> １．行く**の**でしょうか
> ２．行きますでしょうか

Why is の needed between 行く and でしょうか in the first question, but there is no particle between 行きます and でしょうか in the second question?

Context: both questions come from the [this video](https://youtu.be/_oMtifQpT4Q?list=PLOcym2c7xnBwU12Flkm5RcLIEhvURQ8TB&t=780) aimed at Japanese learners (see minute 13:00).

Comment: Can you link the source of those sentences? A bit of context would help as well.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_oMtifQpT4Q&list=PLOcym2c7xnBwU12Flkm5RcLIEhvURQ8TB&index=89&t=0s

It's from this video. But there is no context really. It's just one of the examples. I just noticed that every time plain form is used there is "no" and with masu form there isn't.

Comment: So I thought you made a typo and that your question was why does the 2nd question not need a の, but you edited it back to asking about why the second sentence doesn't need a か. Don't both your examples have か?

Comment: ^ ですよね・・・  「in the second sentence there is no need for "**の**" to form a question?」の書き間違いっぽいですよね・・　@onyx You meant to type の, not か, right?

Comment: @Chocolate そう思ってeditしたのに、もう一度"か”に戻った…

Comment: I'm sorry, there is something that i probably don't understand.
The first sentence is in plain form. And from what i understood, to make a question, you use "の" (いくの？）. The second sentence is in masu form so i figured it supposed to have "か" to form a question (行きますか？).
so i didn't understand why in the first sentence there is need for a question
before でしょか and in the second sentence there isn't.

Comment: The first sentence is not in plain form, but the verb part of it is. The の in the first sentence does not make it a question the か at the end does. When the entire sentence is in plain form and ends in の, which is then either spoken with a rising intonation or written with a question mark, then it is a question, but the presence of a の particle by itself does not turn a sentence into a question. So in response to your comment " i didn't understand why in the first sentence there is need for a question before でしょか", there isn't a question before でしょうか. And 行きますかでしょうか would make no sense.

Comment: I see, then why is "の' needed in the first sentence?

Answer (score 3):

First

- 行くのでしょうか
- 行くでしょうか

are both possible but 行く**ん**でしょうか would be more common in most contexts.

Second,

- 行きますでしょうか

is acceptable in speech but technically wrong as pointed out by @Nameless, which can be felt more strongly in the plain form

- 行きますです

Third,

- 行きます**の**でしょうか

is acceptable to me, but slightly odd. Since 行きますでしょうか is already irregular, there may be not much logic for this, but one thing could be that this の is a nominalizer, which is not usually used after ます.

---

Grammar related to this の.

- ん in んです is [格助詞「の」の音変化](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%82%93/#jn-239154)
- The only [格助詞 definition of の](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AE/#jn-171157) which can follow conjugatable words is 準体助詞 (5-2 in the link).

Another thing is

- です follows directly a conjugatable word only in 未然形 (so 行くです is wrong, 行くでしょうか is fine). ([補説 here](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99/#jn-151501))

Comment: I think this answer only misses what @Nameless pointed out. The の acts as a nominalizer. Therefore, both 行くのでしょうか and 行くでしょうか are ok because noun + でしょうか and verb + でしょうか both works.

Comment: @onyx Nominalizing is not always possible, so that does not imply anything here. E.g. それをするのが正しいです is normal, but it is not possible to say それをしますのが正しいです.

Comment: "行きますでしょうか is acceptable in speech but technically wrong" it's a shame that an educational video throws in technically wrong forms without pointing it out...

Comment: @sundowner I was talking about verbs in plain form of course. Every verb in plain form, From what I know, can be nominalized. When I asked this question I was confused because I didn't understand the role of the の in the sentence (I thought it was a question marker).

Comment: @onyx I'm not sure what your first comment says, then. I say both are ok (same as Nameless) that 行くのでしょうか/行くでしょうか are both ok. in the first point The dubious case is 行きますのでしょうか. Anyway your question as is does not sound like you are asking the role of の, but how necessary の is in the two sentences.

Comment: @sundowner Yeah well, I asked this question three years ago, I'm not sure why it got noticed again. I probably didn't know back then that の can be a nominalizator. Thank you for answering.